# Problems with Dual-Boot OS order and GRUB menu [RESOLVED]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

so I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 dual-booted on my machine. When I used to boot up it would show me the GRUB menu to select the OS I want to use. I recently increased my Ubuntu partitions size, but now it boots straight into Windows 10 without showing me the GRUB menu. What can I do to get it back? I tried efibootmgr and I thought it worked, but my pc still boots into windows 10. Any ideas?

When I try to use BCEdit I get this problem:

[Here I tried to change the boot sequence so that Ubuntu boots first and shows me the GRUB menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQSeC.png)

By the way, my System uses UEFI.

Here is an image of my partitions:
[My partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHab1.png)

Comment: This procedure often fixes this kind of problem and if it doesn’t it provides a load of diagnostics that can help if added to the question. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I tried a bunch of things and this is what worked for me:

I went into the UEFI Firmware settings and put Ubuntu above Windows. Now, instead of pressing esc to go back and then f10 to save, I pressed f10 twice. This saved all the settings and I now get the GRUB menu.